# How to save / restore state of recyclerview in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager. One Fragment has RecyclerView. I want to save the RecyclerView's scroll position.

**I have used this for saving:**

```
 mbundle = new Bundle();
 Parcelable rState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
 mbundle.putParcelable("RECYCLER_STATE", rState);
```

**and used this for restoring:**

```
Parcelable rState= mbundle.getParcelable("RECYCLER_STATE");
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(rState);
```

This works fine if I dont use ViewPager but in ViewPager the position of RecyclerView doesn't restore.

Comment: What are the methods in which you call your code snippets for saving/restoring?

Comment: saving is done in onPause()

Comment: restoring in onStart()

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into this same issue.